# Uncaught Error: You cannot render a <Router> inside another <Router>. You should never have more than one in your app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

This is my main index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Routes from './routes';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { HelmetProvider } from 'react-helmet-async';
import ProductsContextProvider from './contexts/ProductsContext';
import CartContextProvider from './contexts/CartContext';

ReactDOM.render(
  <HelmetProvider>
    <ProductsContextProvider>
      <CartContextProvider>
        <Routes />
      </CartContextProvider>
    </ProductsContextProvider>
  </HelmetProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

This is my index.js in routes folder which handles my routes.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

import Store from '../pages/store';
import About from '../pages/About';
import NotFound from '../pages/NotFound';
import Cart from "../pages/cart";

const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/about" component={<About />} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={<Store />}/>
        <Route path="/cart" component={<Cart />} />
        <Route path="*" component={<NotFound />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default Routes;
```

Still this error is showing:

> Uncaught Error: You cannot render a `<Router>` inside another `<Router>`. You should never have more than one in your app.

I cannot understand where is the routes problem.

Comment: Can you create a running https://codesandbox.io/ demo to reproduce your issue?

Comment: ***Somewhere*** you are rendering another router component. Can you [edit] to include a more complete [mcve]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Routes` component renders a `Router` component and is recursively rendering itself. This nests a router within a router, etc.

Change the name of `Routes` to something else so there's not a naming conflict with the `Routes` component you should be importing from `react-router-dom`. The `Route` component uses the `element` prop for its renderable content.

Example:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes, // <-- add import
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

import Store from '../pages/store';
import About from '../pages/About';
import NotFound from '../pages/NotFound';
import Cart from "../pages/cart";

const AppRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} /> // <-- use element prop
        <Route path="/" element={<Store />}/>
        <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default AppRoutes;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import AppRoutes from './routes';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { HelmetProvider } from 'react-helmet-async';
import ProductsContextProvider from './contexts/ProductsContext';
import CartContextProvider from './contexts/CartContext';

ReactDOM.render(
  <HelmetProvider>
    <ProductsContextProvider>
      <CartContextProvider>
        <AppRoutes />
      </CartContextProvider>
    </ProductsContextProvider>
  </HelmetProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: now its display blank screen with this warning - "Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element or Component. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page."

Comment: @PrinceSaiNi Please check your code that you are using the `element` prop to render the content. RRDv6 `Route` components don't have any `component` prop.

Comment: defined routes like - <Route path="/about" component={<About />} />
          <Route exact path="/" component={<Store />}/>
          <Route path="/cart" component={<Cart />} />
          <Route path="*" component={<NotFound />} /> nothing changes

Comment: @PrinceSaiNi Try `element={<About />}` instead of `component={<About />}`, `element={<Store />}` instead of `component={<Store />}`, etc... for all the routes. `component` just isn't a prop that is used. I don't think I can make this any clearer.